# How to rearrange each cell for each row based on its content?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my 1st question here so I apologize for any formatting mistakes or bad explaining.

I am trying to reorganize a dataframe.

Right now I have a dataframe (df) where, for each line, the content is distributed through its 5 columns. There are 7 possibilities for the content of each cell: document_type, gender, nationality, issuing_date, date_of_expiry, issuing_country and None. Here is an example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
      [["'gender': 'Female'", "'nationality': 'ESP'", "'document_type': 'national_identity_card'", "'date_of_expiry': '2025-11-06'", "'issuing_country': 'ESP'"],
       ["'gender': 'Male'", "'issuing_date': '2015-05'", "'document_type': 'passport'", "'issuing_country': 'FRA'", None],
       ["'document_type': 'national_identity_card'", "'issuing_country': 'GRC'", None, None, None]],
       index=[0,1,2],
       columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'])
```

```
In[1]:df
Out[1]: 
                                     column1                    column2                                    column3                         column4                   column5
0                         'gender': 'Female'       'nationality': 'ESP'  'document_type': 'national_identity_card'  'date_of_expiry': '2025-11-06'  'issuing_country': 'ESP'
1                           'gender': 'Male'  'issuing_date': '2015-05'                'document_type': 'passport'        'issuing_country': 'FRA'                      None
2  'document_type': 'national_identity_card'   'issuing_country': 'GRC'                                      None                            None                       None
```

I want to arrange that table so that I can count the number of males and females, the different nationalities and so on.

I have created a dataframe (df2) with 6 columns (document_type, gender, nationality, issuing_date, date_of_expiry and issuing_country) where I would like to, for each line, organize the content into the correct cell, i.e., in the gender column I would have 'male' or 'female' and the same for the others.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2], columns=['document_type', 'gender', 'nationality', 'issuing_date', 'date_of_expiry', 'issuing_country'])
```

```
In[2]:df2
Out[2]: df2
     document_type gender nationality issuing_date date_of_expiry issuing_country
0              NaN    NaN         NaN          NaN            NaN             NaN
1              NaN    NaN         NaN          NaN            NaN             NaN
2              NaN    NaN         NaN          NaN            NaN             NaN
```

I would like to obtain something like this for df2:

```
           document_type    gender nationality issuing_date  date_of_expiry issuing_country
0 national_identity_card    Female        ESP          None      2025-11-06             ESP
1               passport      Male       None        2015-05           None             FRA
2 national_identity_card      None       None           None           None             GRC
```

The content that was in a certain row should stay in the same row.

I thought about iterating the original dataframe (df), verifying if, for each row and each column, the cell has any string contained in a list (as in `lst = ['document_type', 'gender', 'nationality', 'issuing_date', 'date_of_expiry', 'issuing_country']` ) and, if so, sort it into the correct column.

However, I'm quite new to python and don't know how to go about this. What I have been trying doesn't even come close to resolve this.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a corrupted data structure, so we need first fix the problem , looks like that is a `dict` for each cell , so we using method `ast`

```
import ast
yourdf=('{'+df.stack()+'}').apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series).fillna('').sum(level=0)
yourdf
Out[19]: 
   gender nationality     ...      issuing_country issuing_date
0  Female         ESP     ...                  ESP             
1    Male                 ...                  FRA      2015-05
2                         ...                  GRC             
[3 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexes:

```
string_df = df.applymap(str).sum(axis=1)

columns = ['gender', 'nationality', 'document_type', 'date_of_expiry', 'issuing_date', 'issuing_country']
result = [string_df.str.extract(r"'{}': '([\w-]+)'".format(column), expand=False) for column in columns] 

print(pd.concat(result, axis=1).rename(columns={index: column for index, column in enumerate(columns)}))
```

Output:

```
   gender nationality           document_type date_of_expiry issuing_date  \
0  Female         ESP  national_identity_card     2025-11-06          NaN   
1    Male         NaN                passport            NaN      2015-05   
2     NaN         NaN  national_identity_card            NaN          NaN   

  issuing_country  
0             ESP  
1             FRA  
2             GRC
```